# default double value handling in JsonConvert.SerializeObject

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, double

I'm using `Newtonsoft.Json` in order to serialize a custom class and I have an issue how the library handles the default values for doubles.

The class can be like:

```
class Person
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public double Score {get; set; }
    public bool IsStudent {get; set; }
    public double Weight {get;set; }
}
```

where `FullName` and `Score` are required fields and `IsStudent` is an optional field.

If I serialize the object:

```
Person mark = new Person();
mark.FullName = "Mark Twain";
mark.Score = 0.0;
var jsonMark = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mark);
```

what I get is

```
{
  "FullName": "Mark Twain";
}
```

because 0.0 is the default for `double`.

I need to pass that value always, also if it's `0.0`. If I serialize with `JsonSerializerSettings`

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include;
var jsonMark = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mark);
```

I get

```
{
  "FullName": "Mark Twain",
  "Score": 0.0,
  "IsStudent": false,
  "Weight": 0.0
}
```

so all properties (in this demo `IsStudent` and `Weight`) that I didn't set. In my original code the class contains other `double` and `boolean` fields and to the API I don't need to include them (if I pass `Weight` equals to 0 is not a correct value).

There is a way to change the behavior of the serialization to include only specific fields (in my case just `Score` but not `IsStudent` and `Weight`) or at least only a specific type (`double` but not `bool`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can decorate those specific properties with the [`JsonProperty`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_serialization_jsonproperty.htm) attribute, and specifically set the [`DefaultValueHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm) for each one:

```
class Person
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include)]
    public double Score { get; set; }
    public bool IsStudent { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I added the decorator to the specific property and now the serialization works also when the value is 0.0

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want?

```
class Person
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public double Score {get; set; }
    public bool IsStudent {get; set; }
    public double? Weight {get;set; }
}
```

In this case, if you did't set Weight it will be NULL.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but in my case I can't make the property nullable, so the decorator is a better solution